# How do I find images that can be published here?

Tags: support

Sometimes I would like to illustrate my posts with images. I'd love to post my own self-made pictures but I often do not have any that suit.

Where and how do I find images that have a copyright that allows them to be published here under the [CC by SA 03](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) licence?

---

Manchmal möchte ich meine Beiträge hier mit Bildern illustrieren. Am liebsten würde ich meine eigenen, selbstgemachten Bilder nehmen, aber oft wollen die nicht so recht passen.

Wo und wie finde ich Bilder, deren Urheberrecht eine Veröffentlichung hier unter der [CC by SA 03](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) Lizenz erlaubt? Gibt es spezielle Bilderdatenbanken für lizenzfreie Bilder?

Answer (score 3):

Mit der Google Bildersuche kann man auch nach Bildern mit bestimmten Nutzungsrechten suchen. Dies kann man in der Bildersuche unter "Tools" einstellen:

[image]

Bevor man ein Bild kopiert und hochlädt sollte man sich auf der Originalseite noch einmal die Nutzungsbedingungen genau ansehen. Oft verlangt es nämlich der Urheber, dass man zumindest seinen Namen und/oder die Quelle nennt, wenn man das Bild weiterverwendet (das entspricht der Lizenz hier). Dies sollte man dann selbstverständlich auch tun.

Völlig unproblematisch sind natürlich immer Bilder die in der Public Domain stehen. Oft finden man schöne Bilder in diversen Bilddatenbanken, die aber z.T. eine Registrierung erfordern oder eine Downloadgebühr verlangen.

Unvollständige Liste von Bilderservern mit lizenzfreiem Inhalt:

- [Liste bei Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Public_domain_image_resources)
- [Public Domain Pictures](http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/)
- [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page)
- [Pixabay](https://pixabay.com/)

Comment: Wikipedia has an extensive list of [public domain image resources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Public_domain_image_resources).

Comment: @Martin-マーチン: schöne Liste, Danke. Habe ich gleich eingefügt.

Answer (score 1):

In den meisten Fällen, in denen ich bislang Bilder gesehen habe, abgesehen von Screenshots von Google-NGram oder nicht entzifferbaren Grabsteinen in Sütterlin, waren die Bilder nur Eyecatcher, also triviale Aufmerksamkeitsheischer die das Verständnis einer Frage oder Antwort nicht beförderten. Je weniger es davon gibt, um so besser.

Bei [Openclipart](https://openclipart.org/) findest Du aber Bilder unter Public Domain, die Du bearbeiten und auch relizensieren darfst, und die verschlagwortet sind. Zwar sind das alles SVGs, aber sie werden auch als PNG angeboten.